# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject fails when string contains nulls ("NaN")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, json.net

I am posting data to a controller stringified by knockout:

```
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Action")',
    data: { data: data },
    dataType: 'json'
    ....
})
```

Then server-side, I try to deserialize the data with JsonConvert.

```
var viewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModel>(data,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
        });
```

This fails if data contains null values (serialized as "NaN"), looking like this:

```
"MyField":"NaN"
```

Without null values, it works fine.

I tried adding **NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include/Ignore** to the serializer settings, both without success.

Comment: What does your ViewModel class look like?

Comment: How about not sending `NaN` then? That seems like the sensible solution rather than trying to handle them.

Comment: Hi David, I tried this, somehow didn't work, will try again to make it work

Comment: Why are you serializing null values as NaN instead of null?

Comment: I think we need to see a [mcve] to help you on this one, including a sample `ViewModel` and JSON that reproduce the problem.  Also, what version of Json.NET are you using?  Their handling of `NaN` for doubles has changed over the years, see e.g. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1 and https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/5.0.1.

Comment: Also, is this what you need?  [Removing NaN values in deserialization Web API 2 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42682371/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the problem by adding a small [replacer function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461037/knockout-serialization-with-ko-tojson-how-to-ignore-properties-that-are-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to the knockout stringifier (as suggested by DavidG - thank you, I should have made this work from the beginning).

```
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel, function (key, value) { 
    if (value == "NaN") {
        return;
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
});
```