# Error Parsing Infinity value in Json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am parsing my Json using `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( line );` where line is a json with one of the property is of type array ,something like this

```
"Power": "{[
  -1000,
  -1000,
  -1000,
  -1000,
  -70.78989405217546,
  -31.78104702051717,
  -1.9942114086821978,
  12.365528707410771}]
```

and I am successfully able to parse it but issue happens when in one of the Json lines I have this property of this sort

```
"Power": "{[
  -1000,
  -1000,
  -1000,
  -INF,-INF}]
```

I get error as ***¨Error parsing -Infinity value.¨¨*** Any idea how can I resolve this??

Comment: Pretty sure you will have to [write your own converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814247/serialize-nan-values-into-json-as-nulls-in-json-net) to handle this scenario. Apparently Newtonsoft.Json used to parse this, but it was taken out.

Comment: Yeah I'd expect that to fail.  You can inherit from `JsonConverter` (or the generic version) and handle the read/write yourself.  Personally I would read the JSON file into memory and modify any "bad" values to match what the default converter expects instead.  Both would work.  But if you serialize it back to a file it won't output "-INF" if that's what you really want.

Comment: @Zer0 can you please put this as answer with a sample code as how to handle the read/write

Answer (score -3):

I had this same error and resolved it through dynamic type

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(line);
```

if it doesn't work better to create a class based json structure

use below to generate class

https://quicktype.io/

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<**class_Name>**(line);

Comment: The issue is that Newtonsoft Json **won't** parse the text, as it isn't valid JSON. It doesn't matter which type(s) you want to hydrate from the JSON, it simply won't parse it.