# deserialize double.NaN as null with newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-5

Given this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public double? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize double.NaN as null, it works:

```
var foo = new Foo { Bar = double.NaN };
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new JsonSerializerSettings { FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue });
// {"Bar":null} // ok
```

But to deserialize NaN as null, it doesn't work:

```
var test2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
// {"Bar":"NaN"}
var test3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(test2, new JsonSerializerSettings { FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue });
// test3.Bar = NaN // Not OK, I want it to be null
```

Is there any easier solution than creating his own custom converter ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13801482/717058

Comment: The behavior is correct and logical: deserialization of NaN will produce NaN. I think null produces an empty string in Json. Go for custom converter!

Comment: What is in the test3.Bar after deserializing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use a converter, that would be the least obtrusive way to get what you want. Other solutions here basically pre-/post-processes the conversion which is an unnecessary step. Worst off, you're modifying the class in such a way that is impractical and very manual. Are you going to add an `OnDeserialized()` method to every type you want to ensure every floating point property has "real" values? That method should probably be reserved solely for general library development, not one-offs like this. That doesn't make it "easier."

---

With a converter, you do not have to modify the class at all, you could always specify at conversion and will handle all compatible conversions within the json object (since you say there are many other double properties).

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(test2, new NoNanRealConverter());
```

```
public class NoNanRealConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType;
        return new[] { typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal) }.Contains(type);
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var nullableBase = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType);
        var type = nullableBase ?? objectType;
        if (nullableBase != null && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (type == typeof(double))
        {
            var value = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
            return Double.IsNaN(value) ? null : value;
        }
        else if (type == typeof(float))
        {
            var value = Convert.ToSingle(reader.Value);
            return Single.IsNaN(value) ? null : value;
        }
        return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else if (value is double d && Double.IsNaN(d))
            writer.WriteNull();
        else if (value is float f && Single.IsNaN(f))
            writer.WriteNull();
        else
            writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

If you want even more control over the conversion process, you could make a custom contract resolver.

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin.Martinsson noticed "The behavior is correct and logical: deserialization of NaN will produce NaN", null will produce null. If you don't likeit for some reasons,  the easiest way is to replace NaN with null using string functions

```
jsonString=jsonString.Replace(":NaN",":null");
```

or you can add on OnDeserialized method to class

```
public class Foo
{
.....
  [OnDeserialized]
  private void OnDeserializedBar(StreamingContext context)
  {
   if (Bar.ToString()  == Double.NaN.ToString()) Bar=null;
   }
}
```

I think you can even use both of them in the same time.

Comment: this is not a good idea. You could replace many 'false positives' in the jsonString, it will most probably not contain only instances of the given sample class with that single property.

Comment: @Steeeve It is just a hint since PO didn' t post the real json. But it is working. But I tested your code. It is not working.

Comment: @Serge the real json may contain several fields as double type

Comment: @John, doesn' t matter, all of them will be changed. Or if you want to change only some, you willl have to add a name to replace .

Comment: @Serge if someone add a new Double field in class Foo, he may forget to add the logic on method OnDeserialized. Is there a better solution that say: all double fields in this class cannot have NaN as value and are replaced by null?

Comment: This is why I posted too solutions to see a differenct for you. The first one will be always working, but you need to add the name  for the second

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public double? Bar { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Bar == double.NaN)
            Bar = null;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Serialization Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

Comment: Nice one. What if there's more than one property as "double" in Foo class, can we do better than adding a "if" for each property. For exemple:
if (Bar == double.NaN)
            Bar = null;
if (Bar2 == double.NaN)
           Bar2 = null;
and so on...

Comment: @John Of course. You can add whatever logic you want to the method `OnDeserialized`.

Comment: yeah I meant, if there's too many properties as "double" type in my class Foo. it's cumbersome to add a logic for each of them in the method OnDeserialized. And if someone add a new Double field in class Foo, he may forget to add the logic on method OnDeserialized. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: If you want to achieve that for every property of type double? defined by the class (and optionally any class derived from it), you could use reflection, but that would be another question.